# How do I learn the Chrome console to find my object and its methods?

Tags: reactjs, methods, bitmovin-player

I'm using the bitmovin API js in my React app. I'm stumbling around in the Chrome console to try and find the methods of the API on the player object.

```
> document.getElementById('bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player')
<video id="bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player" preload="metadata" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" src="blob:https://app.totalvu.tv/7805d74c-053d-4484-8866-496ec30c2f2a"></video>

> Object.getPrototypeOf('bitmovin-video-feed-player')
String {"", constructor: ƒ, anchor: ƒ, big: ƒ, blink: ƒ, …}
```

When I open the Prototype String, I don't see the API methods. Instead I get:

```
String {"", constructor: ƒ, anchor: ƒ, big: ƒ, blink: ƒ, …}
anchor: ƒ anchor()
at: ƒ (e)
big: ƒ big()
blink: ƒ blink()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 0
name: "blink"
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
apply: ƒ apply()
arguments: (...)
bind: ƒ bind()
call: ƒ call()
caller: (...)
constructor: ƒ Function()
length: 0
name: ""
toString: ƒ ()
Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()
get arguments: ƒ ()
set arguments: ƒ ()
get caller: ƒ ()
set caller: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: ​
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
bold: ƒ bold()
charAt: ƒ charAt()
charCodeAt: ƒ charCodeAt()
codePointAt: ƒ codePointAt()
concat: ƒ concat()
...
```

I was hoping to find play() rewind() getPlaybackSpeed() etc as listed here:
https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/web/7/docs/interfaces/playerapi.playerapi-1.html

Can you guide me how to navigate the Chrome console and the DOM to find the player and its methods ?

PS old posts have listed all kinds of things like:

```
> console.dir('bitmovin-video-feed-player')
undefined
> console.log(bitmovin-video-feed-player)
VM2946850:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: video is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:22
(anonymous) @ VM2946850:1
> console.log('bitmovin-video-feed-player')
undefined
> dir(window)
undefined
> document.getElementsByTagName('video')
HTMLCollection [video#bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player, bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player: video#bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player]
0: video#bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player
length: 1
bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player: video#bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection
item: ƒ item()
length: (...)
namedItem: ƒ namedItem()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "namedItem"
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
constructor: ƒ HTMLCollection()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLCollection"
get length: ƒ length()
```

Finally, using the React chrome plugins, I can find the methods this way (I'm using 'v' for the expanded lists icon)

```
v t key="feed-player"
(right hand side) props

v mainVideo: {isMuted: false, mainPlayerInstance: {…}, playEvent…}
    v mainPlayerInstance: {_reactInternalFiber: {…}, changeVideoQuality: ƒ bo…}
        v playerInstance: {DRM: {…}, EVENT: {…}, EVENTS: Array(83), LOGLEVEL:…}
...
addEventHandler:ƒ () {}
addMetadata:ƒ () {}
addSubtitle:ƒ () {}
castStop:ƒ () {}
castVideo:ƒ () {}
clearQueryParameters:ƒ () {}
destroy:ƒ () {}
enterFullscreen:ƒ () {}
enterPictureInPicture:ƒ () {}
exitFullscreen:ƒ () {}
exitPictureInPicture:ƒ () {}
fireEvent:ƒ () {}
getAudio:ƒ () {}
getAudioBufferLength:ƒ () {}
getAudioQuality:
```

I need help understanding how to invoke one of these methods on the proper object, in my JS code. "feed-player" in the components doesn't seem related to the bitmovin-video-feed-player. There must be a way to chain from something like :

```
bitmovin.video-feed-player.feed-player.mainVideo.mainPlayerInstance.playerinstance.castVidoeo()
```

for example.

Greatly appreciate the Chrome console Jedi helping me out!

Comment: Well, you are logging the String object..... so.... you might want to start with logging the correct object prototype in your code. What are you hoping to glean from the console that is or isn't included in the official documentation?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for asking. I edited the question to be more clear. I'm wanting to invoke one of the methods, but cannot find the proper sequence of code to access them. So far when I try to run a method I get "{method} is not a funciton.

Comment: I tried this based on @DrewReese comment: Object.getPrototypeOf(document.getElementById('bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player')) but I seem to get the generic HTMLVideoElement {…}

Comment: Progress so far: I can access the generic HTMLElement, but not the element with the extended API methods: document.getElementById('main-iframe-player').contentDocument.getElementById('bitmovinplayer-video-feed-player').play
> ƒ play() { [native code] }

Comment: The `PlayerAPI` is a [global](https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/web/7/docs/globals.html), have you just searched your code for where a player is instantiated? https://cdn.bitmovin.com/player/web/7/docs/index.html

Comment: @DrewReese We have multiple bitmovin player instances in our code at once. I need to find a way to invoke the API on the 'feed-player' that shows up in the React components tool.

Comment: Give them `id` attributes? Create and store React refs to them? I feel there are better/more optimal ways than crawling the DOM. It sort of feels like you're coming at this from the wrong end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend upgrading your app to use Bitmovin Player version 8 (https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/api-reference/web/web-sdk-api-reference-v8#/player/web/8/docs/index.html). You're referencing v7 documentation and v7 is deprecated for quite a while now, thus not further developed or maintained.

To your problem:
As someone already mentioned in the comments, you are accessing the `HTMLVideoElement` DOM element in your code snippets, and not the Bitmovin Player object.
At some point in your app you are creating a Bitmovin Player instance, like this:

```
const player = new Player(document.getElementById('container-id'), config);
```

I'd recommend storing that instance somewhere in your app where you can access it (in my example called `player`). This object contains all the API methods that you can call and that are listed in the public documentation linked above.

Please note that `container-id` is a container element (like a `<div>`) and not the id of the `<video>` tag per default, as the video element is created by the Bitmovin Player.